# NSArray indexOfObject: not acting as I expected

Tags: ios, indexing, nsarray

To make it simple, I'm working on a chat :

I have an NSArray that contains messages, therefore I've created a class Message. Each time I receive a Message object, I'm adding it in the NSArray.

I now have an NSArray that looks like that :

```
(
    "<Message: 0xa8839c0>",
    "<Message: 0x15908480>",
    "<Message: 0x159c6e20>",
    "<Message: 0xa8cb530>",
    "<Message: 0x1593a680>",
    "<Message: 0x956ff50>",
    "<Message: 0x1885f130>",
    "<Message: 0x18121db0>"
)
```

As you can see, all my objects are different.

Now, if I do :

```
for (Message *message in self.messages) {
    NSNumber *idx = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[self.messages indexOfObject:message]];
    NSLog(@"%@ : %@ : %@", idx, message, message.message);
    }
```

I get :

```
(
        1 : "<Message: 0xa8839c0>" : my message 1,
        2 : "<Message: 0x15908480>" : my message 2,
        3 : "<Message: 0x159c6e20>" : my message 3,
        4 : "<Message: 0xa8cb530>" : my message 4,
        5 : "<Message: 0x1593a680>" : my message 5,
        5 : "<Message: 0x956ff50>" : my message 6,
        5 : "<Message: 0x1885f130>" : my message 7,
        5 : "<Message: 0x18121db0>" : my message 8
    )
```

What happened between line 4 and 5 : I've quite the view and came back on the chat. 
But the thing is that the objects in the NSArray are different !

The description of indexOfObject: is :

> *Returns the lowest index whose corresponding array value is equal to a
>   given object.*
>
> *Starting at index 0, each element of the array is sent
>   an isEqual: message until a match is found or the end of the array is
>   reached. This method passes the anObject parameter to each isEqual:
>   message. Objects are considered equal if isEqual: (declared in the
>   NSObject protocol) returns YES.*

I don't get how indexOfObject: can be the same as the objects are different.

What part did I do wrong ?

Thank you

Comment: Did you override `isEqual:`?

Comment: yeah... It's an app developed by someone else and I didn't see that: - (BOOL)isEqual:(id)object
{
    if ([object isKindOfClass:[self class]]) {
        return self.ID == ((Message *)object).ID;
    } else {
        return [super isEqual:object];
    }
}